# jquery - add element text value to end of URL

Tags: jquery

I have a value that loooks like this on top of my page...

```
<div id="mid">
    <span>992839283</span>
</div>
```

...and I always want to copy it to the end of my URL further down page...

```
<div class="murl">
<a href="http://othersite.com/page/go.aspx?id=">my link</a>
</div>
```

...so what is the best way to get my URL to look like this when the window is ready...

```
<div class="murl">
<a href="http://othersite.com/page/go.aspx?id=992839283">my link</a>
</div>
```

I have no idea how to add this value to the end of my URL with minimal code.

thanks for any advice

Comment: There is no way to have the URL be correct on page load, as JavaScript will not run until the page is loaded. It sounds like you should be doing this server-side.

Comment: sorry, i updated my question

Comment: I agree with @thatidiotguy.  The URL should be constructed properly in the first place via the server-side code.

Comment: I agree with both you guys, we will eventually have a claim control that loads this fully, but this is  temporary solution to make the wheels turn until our developers are ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [attr with function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function):

```
$('.murl a').attr('href',function(i,v){
   return v + $('#mid').text();
});
```

Comment: ahh now I can start paying more attention on how to use the return property!  Thank you!

Comment: It just returning the value from function as you normally return the function... here in function params first param is for it's index and second param for its value...